# Weird issue on count and group_by and maybe distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Scenario:

I have a table named snippets with 5 rows,
I have a table named revisions with 15 rows

What I wanted to do was get all snippets, which belongs a `user_id` on revisions, which includes the `snippet_id`.

I have the following mysql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM "snippets" 
INNER JOIN "revisions" 
    ON "user_id" = "1" 
    AND "snippet_id" = "snippets.id"
GROUP BY "snippets"."id" 
ORDER BY "created_at"
```

That should display all snippets where `revisions.user_id = 1`. The problem is, why is my count different? The total results from that query is **5**, but when I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct snippets.id) FROM "snippets" 
INNER JOIN "revisions" 
    ON "user_id" = "1" 
    AND "snippet_id" = "snippets.id"
GROUP BY "snippets"."id";
```

The result is **1 1 1 1 1**

Comment: What is the relationship between `snippets` and `revisions`? Why is that relationship not part of your JOIN conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no meaning for `DISTINCT COUNT(*)`. May be you are looking for `COUNT(DISTINCT someotherfield)` instead of it. Since `COUNT(*)` includes any rows that has `NULL` values.

**Update:*** Don't `COUNT` the same field that you used in the `GROUP BY` clause. That is why you are getting the result `1 1 1 1 1`. In this case remove the `GROUP BY "snippets"."id"` clause.

Comment: @Hermione, You are getting this result `1 1 1 1 1` because you are `GROUP`ing by the `"snippets"."id"` and `COUNT`ing the same field `COUNT(distinct snippets.id)`. Remove the `GROUP BY` clause

Comment: hi, thanks that worked. How about counting using group by instead, is that possible?

Comment: It is possible in case you want to get the count for each group. But something other than the id